# Check the values in complex dict of dicts with another dict of dicts and save it a third dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

The input dictionary of dictionaries are dict1 and dict2.

```
dict1 = {company1:[{'age':27,'weight':200,'name':'john'},{'age':23,'weight':180,'name':'peter'}],
         company2:[{'age':30,'weight':190,'name':'sam'},{'age':32,'weight':210,'name':'clove'},{'age':21,'weight':170,'name':'steve'}],
         company3:[{'age':36,'weight':175,'name':'shaun'},{'age':40,'weight':205,'name':'dany'},{'age':25,'weight':160,'name':'mark'}]
         company4:[{'age':36,'weight':155,'name':'lina'},{'age':40,'weight':215,'name':'sammy'},{'age':25,'weight':190,'name':'matt'}]
        }

dict2 = {company2:[{'age':30},{'age':45},{'age':52}],
         company4:[{'age':43},{'age':67},{'age':22},{'age':34},{'age':42}]
        }
```

I am trying to write a logic where I can check inner key ('age') of each compay key in dict2 exist in same company key dict1, even if one value of inner key 'age' matches with inner key ('age') in dict1 of same company key, then save it to a third dictionary. Please check the below example

**Example**:

```
company2:[{'age':30}]
```

matches with

```
company2:[{'age':30,'weight':190,'name':'sam'}, ...]
```

Also I want to save the key:values of dict1 which doesn't appered in dict2 to the dict3, As we can see in the below example company1 key does not apper in dict2.

**Example**:

```
company1:[{'age':27,'weight':200,'name':'john'},{'age':23,'weight':180,'name':'peter'}]
```

and

```
company3:[{'age':36,'weight':175,'name':'shaun'},{'age':40,'weight':205,'name':'dany'},{'age':25,'weight':160,'name':'mark'}]
```

Expected Output:

```
dict3 = {company1:[{'age':27,'weight':200,'name':'john'},{'age':23,'weight':180,'name':'peter'}],
         company2:[{'age':30,'weight':190,'name':'sam'},{'age':32,'weight':210,'name':'clove'},{'age':21,'weight':170,'name':'steve'}]
         company3:[{'age':36,'weight':175,'name':'shaun'},{'age':40,'weight':205,'name':'dany'},{'age':25,'weight':160,'name':'mark'}]}
```

pardon my explanation!

Comment: Should `company3` be in `dict3`?

Comment: Yes, company3 should be in the dict3, My bad. I will edit.

Comment: I added a company4 in the input  dict1, The 'age' key don't match between compay4 of dict1 and dict2, it should not be in dict3. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution might be better done using some other method more succinctly. However, it accomplishes the desired result.

```
from pprint import pprint

dict3 = dict()

dict1 = {'company1':[{'age':27,'weight':200,'name':'john'},{'age':23,'weight':180,'name':'peter'}],
         'company2':[{'age':30,'weight':190,'name':'sam'},{'age':32,'weight':210,'name':'clove'},{'age':21,'weight':170,'name':'steve'}],
         'company3':[{'age':36,'weight':175,'name':'shaun'},{'age':40,'weight':205,'name':'dany'},{'age':25,'weight':160,'name':'mark'}],
         'company4':[{'age':36,'weight':155,'name':'lina'},{'age':40,'weight':215,'name':'sammy'},{'age':25,'weight':190,'name':'matt'}]
        }

dict2 = {'company2':[{'age':30},{'age':45},{'age':52}],
         'company4':[{'age':43},{'age':67},{'age':22},{'age':34},{'age':42}]
        }

for company, array in dict1.items():
    if company not in dict2:
        dict3[company] = array
    else:
        # all the ages for this company in dict1
        ages = set(map(lambda x: x['age'], array))

        for dictref in dict2[company]:
            if dictref['age'] in ages:
                dict3[company] = array
                break
pprint(dict3)
```

Output was

```
{'company1': [{'age': 27, 'name': 'john', 'weight': 200},
              {'age': 23, 'name': 'peter', 'weight': 180}],
 'company2': [{'age': 30, 'name': 'sam', 'weight': 190},
              {'age': 32, 'name': 'clove', 'weight': 210},
              {'age': 21, 'name': 'steve', 'weight': 170}],
 'company3': [{'age': 36, 'name': 'shaun', 'weight': 175},
              {'age': 40, 'name': 'dany', 'weight': 205},
              {'age': 25, 'name': 'mark', 'weight': 160}]}
```